# AS3 Loader Class best practice

Tags: actionscript-3

Recently in a project I configured a custom Loader class as follows
First I define my Loader as a private variabel

```
private var _myLdr:Loader

//Then in the constructor

_myLdr = new Loader();          
_myLdr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, doneImgLoad );
_myLdr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loadProgress );
_myLdr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError );
```

And then finally when I need to load a new asset I call my Loader instance via a public method

```
_myLdr.load(new URLRequest ('myswftoLoad.swf') );
```

So far so good....UNLESS you happen to view your page using the debug version of FlashPlayer 9.024  in which case you get

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::Loader/_load()
```

WTF???!!

So to correct I need to instantiate a new loader EVERY time I load a new asset.

Can someone tell me which method would be considered a 'best practice'?

Answer (score 0):

A `Loader` instance can have [utmost one child](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html#load()) at a time. Call `_myLdr.unload();` before issuing subsequent `load()` requests with same Loader instance.

That being said, I would rather create a new `Loader` instance for each loads (and make sure that previous instances are properly unloaded when they are no longer needed).

Comment: Tried that and I still get '
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
 at flash.display::Loader/unload()'
....although strange that I ONLY get the error with the 9.024 version of the debug player and not version 10 of the debug player.  The other reason creating a new Loader instance each time you load an external asset seems counter-intuitive is that I assume each new Loader instance adds a small amount to the memory used by the application.  In my case the application is used in a kiosk setting and I'm trying to avoid any memory leaks....

Comment: Am going to assume that 'best practice' would be to create  new Loader instance(with associated listeners' each time. But also to have a 'cleanup' method that removes the loader from the display list as well as its listeners.

Comment: Are you adding `loader.content` to some other parent? By default it will be the child of the corresponding `Loader` object that loaded it - and I guess unload method might be calling `loader.remove(loader.content)` and will fail if you are adding loader.content to something else.